# Show equations determine local functions and determine $\frac{du}{dx}$

Tags: calculus

Show that the pair of equations:

$x^2-y^2-u^3+v^2+4=0$, and $2xy+y^2-2u^2+3v^4+8=0$

determine local functions $x(u,v)$ and $y(u,v)$ defined for $(u,v)$ near $u=2$ and $v=1$ such that $x(2,1)=2$ and $y(2,1)=-1$. Compute $\frac{du}{dx}$ at $(2,1)$.

I have rearranged these equations and solved for $y(u,v)$, but I end up with an equation which is too long to have any use, how best should I go about solving this problem. Thanks in advance for the help.

Also any hints would also be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can not directly addressed, then the implicit function theorem:

The pair of implicit function

$F_1(u,v,x,y)=x^2-y^2-u^3+v^2+4=0$

$F_2(u,v,x,y)=2xy+y^2-2u^2+3v^4+8=0$

determine local functions x(u,v) and y(u,v) defined for (u,v) near u=2 and v=1 such that x(2,1)=2 and y(2,1)=−1

when $F_1(2,1,2,-1)=0,\,\,F_1(2,1,2,-1)=0$

and there are continuous 1. partial derivatives of functions $F_1, F_2$ by all variables near (2,1,2,-1),

and determinant 
$\begin{vmatrix} \frac{\partial F_1}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial F_1}{\partial y} \\ \frac{\partial F_2}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial F_2}{\partial y} \end{vmatrix} \neq 0$ in (2,1,2,-1).

I don't understand the requirement to calculate the normal derivative $\frac{du}{dx}$ for a function of two variables x = x (u,v).