# At what points can we solve for F(x, y, u, v) = 0 for u, v in terms of x, y? Also need to compute $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}$

Tags: real-analysis, implicit-function-theorem

Q: Let $F$ be defined by $F(x, y, u, v) = (u^3+vx+y, uy+v^3-x).$At what points can we solve for $F(x, y, u, v)=0 $ in terms of x, y? Also compute $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}$.

(And I found this pretty similar to [Show equations determine local functions and determine $\frac{du}{dx}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/910869/show-equations-determine-local-functions-and-determine-fracdudx)) It's just that I have to find the points myself...

It seems that I can only find the representation of x and y in terms of u, v($x=\frac{-u^4+v^3}{1+uv}, y=\frac{-u^3-v^4}{1+uv}$), which is easier.

If I need to find u and v in terms of x, y, I have to solve the equations $u^3+vx+y=0$ and $uy+v^3-x =0 $, u and v are to the power of 3... seems impossible, I tried and failed. And if I can do this I believe computing $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}$ isn't hard. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Note that you are NOT asked to *solve* "in practice", only *where* could you solve "in theory". The whole point of the implicit function theorem is that solving is not possible, or not convenient.

Comment: Could you offer me more clues? Solving in theory means I still need to do something with the equations.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the first equation and assume that $u,v$ are a function of $x,y$, so you have:
$$F_1(x,y,u(x,y),v(x,y))=u^3(x,y)+v(x,y)\,x+y=0$$
Then, by the chain rule, you can derive with respect to $x$:
$$\frac{d F_1}{d x}=\frac{\partial F_1}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial F_1}{\partial u}\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial F_1}{\partial v}\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}=0$$

Take now the second equation:
$$F_2(x,y,u(x,y),v(x,y))=u(x,y)\, y+v^3(x,y)-x=0$$
and derive again with respect to $x$:
$$\frac{d F_2}{d x}=\frac{\partial F_2}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial F_2}{\partial u}\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial F_2}{\partial v}\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}=0$$

Together, these two equations form a *linear* system from where you can solve for $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x},\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}$. But the theory of linear systems gives us conditions as to when a solution exists: the matrix of coefficients must be invertible. This is the Jacobian matrix:
$$
J_f=
\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{\partial F_1}{\partial u} & \frac{\partial F_1}{\partial v} \\
\frac{\partial F_2}{\partial u} & \frac{\partial F_2}{\partial v} 
\end{pmatrix}
$$
So at every point where the Jacobian is nonsingular, the implicit function theorem guarantees that the functions that define $u,v$ as functions of $x,y$ **exist**, although maybe you cannot express them in a closed formula.

Comment: Oops...I made a typo... it's $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}$, not $\frac{\partial x}{\partial u}$, sorry for causing trouble!

Comment: Yes, this is slightly bothering because I have to rewrite everything :)

Comment: No... I think it's similar I can work on myself thanks!

Comment: No problem, just now the expression of the points where the Jacobian is singular is not so obvious...

Comment: It should be ok and I appreciate your patience!